# How does Wordpress add the comments and comment form to posts

Tags: posts, comments, tabs

I have created tabs in my single.php file. I would like to move my comments from the bottom of the posts to the comments tab. I have can't seem to find how to do this. I have copied everything from the comments.php to it's tab in the single.php but the only thing it outputs is the comment form, not any of the comments.The comment form does work as well because it adds comments to post that I am on.

Answer (score 0):

My appologies. I was busy in the content-single.php. I have manged to sort this out by editing the single.php file in my child theme.

Comment: There is no reason to appologies for asking a question as no one knows everything, but if you bothered with an answer please edit it to explain better what you have done. Right now it will not help anyone.

Comment: Didn't really do anything. I was in the content-single.php file in the 2016 theme and I couldn't work out how the comments were incorporated at the bottom of the posts. Wordpress uses the single.php file to display posts and the comments. So I created my tabs in the single.php file and removed them from the content-single.php, which resides in the template parts.